# Съезжает последний элемент GridLayout при центрировании

Tags: android

Нужно чтоб надпись "100%" располагалась так же, как и остальные. Как это сделать?

```
<GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="2"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:useDefaultMargins="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
>

<com.milkmachine.nutrcalc.data.CustomProgress
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
    android:text="90%"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<com.milkmachine.nutrcalc.data.CustomProgress
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
    android:text="90%"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<com.milkmachine.nutrcalc.data.CustomProgress
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
    android:text="90%"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<com.milkmachine.nutrcalc.data.CustomProgress
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="100%"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"/>

</GridLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепутал gravity с layout_gravity. 
PS: Не надо так!

Answer (score 0):

Может, уменьшите немного ширину вашего CustomProgress везде, где он используется? Например:

```
<com.milkmachine.nutrcalc.data.CustomProgress
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    />
```

Comment: это не помогает